# .searchable redrawing view

Tags: swiftui, view, .searchable

I'm getting tripped up an an issue with .searchable.

I want to use the environment object isSearching to hide a view, and in order to do that, according to apple docs, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/performing-a-search-operation, I have to move the .searchable modifier outside of the view, and use an observable object or environment object to store the search text.

However on doing this, it seems to be redrawing the view after every letter is typed into the search bar, the excluded items appear for a split second and it looks janky.

I've tried with an environment object, injected from the root view, an observable object and a state object, same result.

I've attempted to include a minimum replicable example below. Is there a way to stop this from redrawing, or another way to access the isSearching variable?

Many thanks

```
/* This is the search view. This works fine, when I have the .searchable and the searchText variable in this view. */

struct Temp: View {
    @ObservedObject var searchModel: SearchModel
    @Environment(\.isSearching) private var isSearching
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: false)],
        animation: .default)
    private var savedItem: FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: some View {
        List {
            if isSearching {
            }
            else {
                withAnimation {
                    Button(action: {self.shouldPresentSheet.toggle()}) {
                        BeansListButton()
                            .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    }
                }.listRowBackground(Color("colorBeanListBG"))
            }
            ForEach(savedItem, id: \.self) { item in
                Section {
                    NavigationLink {
                        Detail(item: item)
                    } label: {
                        ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing){
                            ListItem(brand: item.brand!, product: item.product!, weight: item.weight, rating: Int(item.rating))
                        }
                    }
                }
                .listRowBackground(Color("colorBeanListBG"))
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
        }
        .onChange(of: searchModel.searchText) { search in
            let productKeyPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "product CONTAINS[cd] %@", search)
            let brandKeyPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "brand CONTAINS[cd] %@", search)
            let orPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .or, subpredicates: [productKeyPredicate, brandKeyPredicate])
            
            if search.isEmpty {
                savedItem.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
            } else {
                savedItem.nsPredicate = orPredicate
            }
        }
    }
}

/* But in order to access the isSearching environment object, everything needs to be nested, and an observable object is needed. 

This is the parent view */

@ObservedObject private var searchModel = SearchModel()

NavigationStack {
    Temp(searchModel: searchModel)
        .searchable(text: $searchModel.searchText, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))
}

/* And the ViewModel */ 
class SearchModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var searchText: String = ""
}
```

Comment: The code you posted would be a much better minimal reproducible example if you made it so that one can directly paste that code into an empty project and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok, it's tricky to create a fully reproducible example with cora data and fetched results though. I'm not sure if that element is what's causing the redraw.

Comment: Is CoreData necessary to reproduce this? What happens if you just search an array of things instead?

Comment: I’ll have to try that. I had this entire thing built and working until I decided to try to use isSearching which requires passing the searchText somehow

Comment: You shouldn't use `@ObservedObject` where it is owned -- use `@StateObject` where it is owned (eg in parent view)

Comment: Hey, no that doesn't work, I've tried that, @statobject in parent, and pass it to the child as an ObservedObject

Comment: I made a test version of this using only an array and it works fine, so it is related to onChange in combo with core data and nspredicate

Answer (score 0):

I’ve found a workaround for this now, and I’m hiding the view using .onChange of searchText.

It’s not ideal as it only disappears now when you start typing not when the search bar has focus.

If anyone can tell me why it’s redrawing after every letter when passing the searchText as a binding please let me know thanks

Comment: I had a similar issue using `.searchable` in combo with Realm ... redrawing at every keyboard stroke. In my case as a workaround I only pass the searchString up the hierarchy when the user hits return. Also not ideal, so if you find something, let me know.